# Should I delete excess EFI System Partition?

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, efi

So I ran into a booting problem today, which i managed to solve by creating EFI System Partition (I somehow must have deleted that by accident).
And as you can see, I kind of "overdo" that, and created too much of them.. is it okay to leave them like that? If not, which one should I remove, so as not to mess it even more?

[My view of Disk Manager System Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9oQ6.png)

Comment: I would be reinstalling the OS and then not mess with partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, to clean up, you can delete all EFI partitions as long as they are empty and then move the unallocated ones together and add them to your C:/

But since I do not know what went wrong, I would actually suggest you to do a backup of your files and reinstall the OS.

A clean reinstall of the OS will give you a working partition table and when you wanna create more partitions, for example to create one for personal data only etc., you can look that up on the web, where you can find good and detailed guides on how to do that.

Changing partitions in general should only be done if you know exactly what you are doing. It can lead to massive data-loss or inoperability of your system.